# Conversion of a .csv file to an .xls file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm looking to automate the conversion of a .csv file to an .xls file.

I try this in Python:

```
import os
import csv
import xlsxwriter

f = open('U:\\INSEE\\Data.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

# Création d'un nouveau fichier
fichier = xlsxwriter.Workbook('U:\\INSEE\\fichier.xlsx')
Feuil = fichier.add_worksheet('Feuil')

i=0

for row in reader:
    Feuil.write(i,0,row)
    i=i+1


reader.close()
fichier.close()
```

or this :

```
import os 
csv_file = 'C:/Users/../fichier.csv' 
excel_file = os.path.splitext(csv_file)[0] + '.xlsx'
```

All this does not work. Can you help me please?

Comment: *All this does not work.*  You're expected to tell us what this means, since, you know, we can't read your mind. If there's an error, please include the trace, if there's not an error, please include a good description of how the output results deviate from your expectations, preferably with a small set of sample data (2 lines of CSV data probably sufficient) which illustrate the problem.

Comment: Also, use appropriate tags :) This is obviously (to me) a python question but you tagged with `excel` (not a programming language), `csv` (not a programming language` and `automation` (also not a programming language), so that tends to limit this question's exposre to people who would be likely knowledgeable about the actual language and packages you're using...

Comment: Thank you for your advice. With what I have tried but nothing results, that's the problem. I programmed in Python but didn't tag it because I'm not opposed to another language :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use pandas since it makes this incredibly easy.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.read_csv('U:\\INSEE\\Data.csv',sep=';')
csv_file.to_excel('U:\\INSEE\\fichier.xlsx')
```

Comment: It can't replicate this problem. From my research, it seems that you  may have non UTF-8 compliant characters in your file. What type of data is present in your file?

Comment: With "csv_file = pd.read_csv('U:\\INSEE\\Data.csv',sep=';',encoding=‌​'latin-1'), it works.

Comment: Now I'm curious what characters are present that force `latin-1` encoding. Glad you were able to get this working.